# Second pass in multipass effect is ignored

Tags: shaders, directx, sharpdx

I am trying to render my vertecies in 2 passes, but it seems I am doing something wrong, because only one pass applying. I cannot make the second one work despite that second pass is applying.

Here is my code:

```
var effectByteCode =            ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(@"Content\Effects\SpriteBatchEffect.fx", "fx_5_0"); 
spriteBatchEffect = new Effect(this.graphicsDevice, effectByteCode);
pass = spriteBatchEffect.GetTechniqueByName("SpriteBatch").GetPassByIndex(0);
//Layout from VertexShader input signature
var passSignature = pass.Description.Signature;
layout = new InputLayout(graphicsDevice, passSignature, inputElements);
```

Effect code:

```
    Texture2D Texture;
    SamplerState TextureSampler;

matrix OrthoMatrix;

struct VertexInputType
{
   float4 position : SV_POSITION;
   float4 color: COLOR;
   float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
   float4 position : SV_POSITION;
   float4 color: COLOR;
   float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

PixelInputType SpriteVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
   PixelInputType output;
   output.color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
   output.position = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);

   // Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
   input.position.w = 1.0f;

   output.position = mul(input.position, OrthoMatrix);

   // Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
   output.tex = input.tex;
   output.color = input.color;
   return output;
}

float4 SpritePixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
   return Texture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.tex)* input.color;

}

float4 SpritePixelShader2(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
   /*return Texture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.tex)+ input.color;*/
   return float4(1,0,0,0);
}


technique10 SpriteBatch
{
   pass P0
   {
      SetGeometryShader(0);
      SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, SpriteVertexShader()));
      SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, SpritePixelShader()));
   }

   pass P1
   {
      SetGeometryShader(0);
      SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, SpriteVertexShader()));
      SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, SpritePixelShader2()));
   }
}
```

And how I am using it:

```
graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffers(0, vertexBufferBinding);


     var technique = tempEffect.GetTechniqueByName("SpriteBatch");
     for (int i = 0; i < technique.Description.PassCount; i++)
     {
        var localpass = technique.GetPassByIndex(i);
        //if (localpass.IsValid)
        {
           localpass.Apply(graphicsDevice);
           graphicsDevice.DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);
        }
     }
```

Could someone point me why second pass is not apply? What I am missing here?
Note that I am not using SharpdDX toolkit - just plain SharpDX + C#

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found an issue - I had to change my depth stencil state to make second pass enabled, because by default second pass discarded by depth stencil state.